# Setting the Indexer Scedule when using “Update by schedule"

Tags: cron, magento-2.2.5, index

I understand that using `Update by schedule` refers to the cron schedule for timing, when changing the Mode under Index Management. But I require some clarification.

**M1**

In M1, you would set the schedule under:

`System > Configuration > Advanced > Index Management`.

[image]

**M2**

In M2, I figure the below setting is comparable under:

`Stores > Configuration > Advanced > System > Cron (Scheduled Tasks)`.

[image]

**Objective**

My objective is to have all Indexers that use `Update by schedule`, to run once per day at midnight.

**Question**

From what I can tell from the default value of "1", the Indexer runs every minute.

If I wanted the Indexer to run everyday at midnight, would I set Generate Schedules Every to "0", "1440" or something else? And would the other values in the section need changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting this question, I decided to carry out my own experiment. I set Generate Schedules Every to "1440" in the hopes that Magento would treat that as a Midnight value. However, it seems that Magento instead treats this value as "1440" minutes from the time that you set it (give or take a few minutes).

So it looks like you can't set it by time-of-day, but just minutes triggered from the time you save the configuration.